# Action replay in unity 3d

Tags: unity, c#, replays

I'm trying to record an action replay for the last 5 seconds. I'm building a bowling game and want to perform an action replay for when the ball strikes the pin by capturing with camera's with different angles. I'm unaware of how this thing could be done. Do i have to record a clip at run time for that and play it at the right time to display action replay? or something else?

Below is the code. Please refer to it.

**Replay.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Replay : MonoBehaviour
{


    public Text timertext;


    public GameObject pin1;
    public GameObject pin2;
    public GameObject pin3;
    public GameObject pin4;
    public GameObject pin5;
    public GameObject pin6;
    public GameObject pin7;
    public GameObject pin8;
    public GameObject pin9;
    public GameObject pin10;

    static int count = 50;



    Vector3 pin1po;
    Vector3 pin2po;
    Vector3 pin3po;
    Vector3 pin4po;
    Vector3 pin5po;
    Vector3 pin9po;
    Vector3 pin10po;

    List<Vector3> PinsPosition1;
    List<Vector3> PinsPosition2;
    List<Vector3> PinsPosition3;
    List<Vector3> PinsPosition4;
    List<Vector3> PinsPosition5;
    List<Vector3> PinsPosition6;
    List<Vector3> PinsPosition7;
    List<Vector3> PinsPosition8;
    List<Vector3> PinsPosition9;
    List<Vector3> PinsPosition10;

    List<Quaternion> PinsRotation1;
    List<Quaternion> PinsRotation2;
    List<Quaternion> PinsRotation3;
    List<Quaternion> PinsRotation4;
    List<Quaternion> PinsRotation5;
    List<Quaternion> PinsRotation6;
    List<Quaternion> PinsRotation7;
    List<Quaternion> PinsRotation8;
    List<Quaternion> PinsRotation9;
    List<Quaternion> PinsRotation10;

    public static bool start;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        start = false;

        pin1po = new Vector3();
        pin2po = new Vector3();
        pin3po = new Vector3();
        pin4po = new Vector3();
        pin5po = new Vector3();
        pin9po = new Vector3();
        pin10po = new Vector3();

        PinsPosition1 = new List<Vector3>();
        PinsPosition2 = new List<Vector3>();
        PinsPosition3 = new List<Vector3>();
        PinsPosition4 = new List<Vector3>();
        PinsPosition5 = new List<Vector3>();
        PinsPosition6 = new List<Vector3>();
        PinsPosition7 = new List<Vector3>();
        PinsPosition8 = new List<Vector3>();
        PinsPosition9 = new List<Vector3>();
        PinsPosition10 = new List<Vector3>();

        PinsRotation1 = new List<Quaternion>();
        PinsRotation2 = new List<Quaternion>();
        PinsRotation3 = new List<Quaternion>();
        PinsRotation4 = new List<Quaternion>();
        PinsRotation5 = new List<Quaternion>();
        PinsRotation6 = new List<Quaternion>();
        PinsRotation7 = new List<Quaternion>();
        PinsRotation8 = new List<Quaternion>();
        PinsRotation9 = new List<Quaternion>();
        PinsRotation10 = new List<Quaternion>();

        pin1po = pin1.transform.position;
        pin2po = pin2.transform.position;
        pin3po = pin3.transform.position;
        pin4po = pin4.transform.position;
        pin5po = pin5.transform.position;
        pin9po = pin9.transform.position;
        pin10po = pin10.transform.position;

    }


    public void Checktime(bool time)
    {
        start = time;

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (start == true)
        {
            count = count - 1;

            if (count < 1)
            {

                PinsPosition1.Add(pin1.transform.position);
                PinsRotation1.Add(pin1.transform.rotation);

                PinsPosition2.Add(pin2.transform.position);
                PinsRotation2.Add(pin2.transform.rotation);

                PinsPosition3.Add(pin3.transform.position);
                PinsRotation3.Add(pin3.transform.rotation);

                PinsPosition4.Add(pin4.transform.position);
                PinsRotation4.Add(pin4.transform.rotation);

                PinsPosition5.Add(pin5.transform.position);
                PinsRotation5.Add(pin5.transform.rotation);

                PinsPosition6.Add(pin6.transform.position);
                PinsRotation6.Add(pin6.transform.rotation);

                PinsPosition7.Add(pin7.transform.position);
                PinsRotation7.Add(pin7.transform.rotation);

                PinsPosition8.Add(pin8.transform.position);
                PinsRotation8.Add(pin8.transform.rotation);

                PinsPosition9.Add(pin9.transform.position);
                PinsRotation9.Add(pin9.transform.rotation);

                PinsPosition10.Add(pin10.transform.position);
                PinsRotation10.Add(pin10.transform.rotation);

            }

        }
        if(count<-100)
        {
            return;
        }


    }


}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Rendering the scene from multiple angles at once in case the player wants to see a replay might be quite performance-intense. Also, you won't have enough memory to do that. 1920px * 1080px * 3 byte per pixel * 5 seconds * 60 frames per second * 10 perspectives = 17 GB of memory. Well, you could try to compress the videos in real-time, but that will make it even slower and will impair quality.

What I would suggest instead is to add a script `Recorder` to each replay-relevant game object which saves the `transform.position` and `transform.rotation` of the game object on each `Update` to a `List`.

In "Replay Mode", you disable all components which control the position of these objects and replace them with a script `Replayer` which then processes the list of transforms the `Recorder` saved update-by-update.

You can then replay the clip as often as you want with the camera in any position you like. You can even let the player control the camera during replay.

Comment: You mean to say that i should make a script that records the position of the ball and the pins and its collision, but how would i save the scene?

Comment: @user100020 Yes, that's what I mean. What exactly do you mean with "save the scene"? In a bowling game, you would reset the scene  after each throw anyway.

Comment: @user100020 I don't understand what you are asking. Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: You asked to save the values of rotation and position of the gameObjects, that's what i understood. But those would be the values only. Does that mean that i have to create a separate scene for that and initially apply those values(i.e position and rotation of the game objects) to that particular scene?

Comment: Your scene likely has more than just the pins and the bowling ball. So I would reload the scene, load the pin configuration at the start of the throw, and then let the Replayer scripts do their thing while giving the player some camera and playback controls. There are several ways to do that. You could have multiple scenes which you load and unload additively (one for the environment which never changes and one for the pins and ball), or you could have everything in one scene and activate, deactivate or re-Instantiate things as needed.

Comment: Alright! This time i got your point.You mentioned in your answer that i have to disable the components which holds the position/rotation of the gameobject. Destroying the script attached to the gameobjects would do that?

Comment: @user100020 What I meant is that you likely have a `Rigidbody` on your pins and bowling ball to control their movement (and when you don't, then you likely have some homebrewed physics controller script). When you have that and manipulate the transform in a different way, you confuse the Unity physics engine, which can lead to all kinds of weird effects. That's why you should disable the Rigidbody while the replay mode is active. You could of course remove the Rigidbody entirely, but just setting `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().enabled = false` is likely much more lightweight.

Comment: Oh i missed that point. Thank you very much @Philipp. Your explanation was easy and understandable. No ill have a try on that. Will let you know if any issue occurs. :)

Comment: You should use `FixedUpdate()` instead of `Update()`, to avoid issues stemming from different rendering times of each frame between the recording and the playback phases.

Comment: @Philipp, Sir i have managed to save the pins and ball position and rotation in the script. Now how would i use it? I mean do i need to attach that script to new camera? and am i moving in the right direction?

Comment: @user100020 There is no right direction, only the direction which is right for you. What I would do is attach an individual script to each game-object which records and replays the movement of that particular game object only. But just having one global controller-script which does this for all game-objects at once would also be a legitimate way to do this.

Comment: You mean to say, I have to attach the script to all the 10 pins individually?

Comment: That's what i tried so far, made a global script that records the position of all the pins. But now i dont have idea how would i make it use and play again. Initially i used another camera to display the replay. I'm attaching the replay script to that camera. But then what to do?

Comment: @user100020 The script you added to the question seems to follow the strategy of one global controller-script. That means it would make sense to put the replay-functionality in a global script, too. I would not attach such scripts to the camera (even though it would theoretically work). The camera should only have scripts which control the camera itself. A script which controls things which happen in the scene should be on objects in the scene. It's not uncommon to have an invisible object in the scene which does nothing but host all global scripts. But that's a matter of personal taste.

Comment: Yeah i have used the replay script and attached it with an empty GameObject. So by your explanation i can run that script upon that gameobject too?

Comment: @user100020 Running *this particular script in the question* on every game object would be a bad idea because then you have copies of the positions of all game-objects in every single game-object. That would be a waste of resources. But you could have a script which only records and replays the movement of the one game-object it is attached to. That's what I would recommend because it's far more reusable (if you want another object to be included in replays, you just need to drop that script on it and don't have to change any code).

Comment: That means i should attach script individually to all gameobjects that i would want to display in replay. That's not a problem. The issue is about reusing the script with values containing positions and rotations of the gameobject. Making an instance of the script would do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59006/discussion-between-philipp-and-user100020).

Comment: @Philipp please refer to my new question 
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/141356/move-gameobject-with-defined-lists-of-position-and-rotation