# Move GameObject with defined lists of position and rotation

Tags: unity, movement

I'm working on playing a replay on every strike. For that I'm recording the positions and rotation of the sphere in the list individually. I now have the values reside in the list. How do i move my sphere with the defined pos and rot. Below is what I've tried so far.

**Replay.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Replay : MonoBehaviour
{

    BallRecorder script;

    public List<Vector3> position;

    public List<Quaternion> rotation;




    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        script = GetComponent<BallRecorder>();

        position = new List<Vector3>();
        rotation = new List<Quaternion>();

        position = script.position;   // Now contains all the values of the sphere(positions) 
        rotation = script.rotation;   // Now contains all the values of the sphere(rotation) 



        foreach (Vector3 av in position)
        {
            transform.position = av;  //transferring position to the sphere
        }




     }
```

**BallRecorder.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallRecorder : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization

  public  List<Vector3> position;
  public  List<Quaternion> rotation;
    static int count = 50;


    void Start () {

        position = new List<Vector3>();

        rotation = new List<Quaternion>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        count = count - 1;

        if (count < 1)
        {
            position.Add(transform.position);
            rotation.Add(transform.rotation);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have timestamps representing when each position/rotation snapshot was recorded? Or were they recorded in FixedUpdate to keep the timestep between them consistent?

Comment: Yes they were recorded in FixedUpdate method

Comment: ...your newly added BallRecorder code has the recording in Update, not FixedUpdate. Did you change it for some reason?

Comment: Could you tell me if you have solution for this problem? I am trying to build a replay from previously saved position and my code is very similar for your initial code. If you have solution could you post? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be inclined to do this as a Coroutine like so, letting us start the playback by calling `StartCoroutine(PlayFrom(0f));`

```
IEenumerator PlayFrom(float time = 0f) {
    // As long as there's still more recording to play, 
    // update our transform to match the replay data at this moment.
    while(Playback(time)) {
        // Wait until next frame.
        yield return null;

        // Advance the playhead by deltaTime and loop again.
        // You can set Time.timeScale to get slow-motion replays this way.
        time += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

bool Playback(float time) {
    // Convert the playback time to a position in our sample array.
    // (Here I'm assuming the current fixedDeltaTime is the same one used to record)
    float sample = time / Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    // Round down to the position & rotation sample just before this moment.
    // (Here I'm assuming time is non-negative)
    int previousIndex = (int)(sample);

    int last = positions.Count - 1;
    if(previousIndex < last) {
        // We have another snapshot ahead, so we'll interpolate smoothly between them.
        int nextIndex = previousIndex + 1;
        float interpolation = sample - previousIndex;

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(
                                position[previousIndex],
                                position[nextIndex],
                                interpolation);

        // Slerp is technically a more consistent option here, since it keeps
        // the rate of change even over the course of the interpolation.
        // But each step is usually too small for this difference to be visible.
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(
                                rotation[previousIndex],
                                rotation[nextIndex].
                                interpolation);

        // Signal that there's still more replay past here.
        return true;
    }

    // Here we're off the end of the timeline, so we'll hold on the last snapshot.
    transform.position = position[last];
    transform.rotation = rotation[last];

    // Signal that we're at the end of the replay.
    return false;
}
```

Pulling out `Playback` as its own method also lets you call it separately if you want to seek to a particular freezeframe in the replay, or reverse time and rewind the recording, or use a shared playhead controller to scrub through the timeline, things like that.

Comment: Is the algorithm recording with snapshots? or it is the forward algorithm for what I've done so far(i.e by saving positions and rotations in a list)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You can see the code above uses the position and rotation lists defined in your question. (BTW, you don't need to create a new list a la `position = new List<Vector3>()` if you're just going to assign an existing list into that slot like `position = script.position` - this overwrites the reference to that `new List`, so you can skip ever creating it if you're not going to use it)

Comment: Beauty! It's working. But just a little confused. It's playing back twice.

Comment: You mean it plays to the end, then repeats again from the beginning, after a single call to `StartCoroutine(PlayFrom(0f))`? This should only happen if your position list contains the same data twice. You can `Debug.Log` the `time` or `previousIndex` variables to double-check where you are in the playback.

Comment: Yes you are right Sir! It's happening because i didn't apply any stop to my recording positions from ball. Can you please suggest me how would i stop recording. I tried using Timer technique, but the timer starts when the game is executed. I edited my question.

Comment: Myself, I'd be inclined to make a single script handle both recording & playback. I'd make a recording Coroutine similar to the playback one (but using `yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate()` instead),  and then I can stop it when I want using `StopCoroutine()` and start my playback coroutine instead. :)

Comment: Thanks for the nice suggestion. Switching from update to FixedUpdate worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Start` method doesn't make much sense.

```
    foreach (Vector3 av in position)
    {
        transform.position = av;  //transferring position to the sphere
    }
```

This replaces the position of the object with those from the list one after another. But the problem with this is that it does all that during the start-method. So when Start is over, the object ends up with the last position and the player has no chance to see those between. What you need to do is have a counter-variable which says at which point in the recording you are currently and then transfer the positions during the `Update` method, one after another.

```
int current = 0;

void Update() {
     if (current < position.Count) {
         transform.position = position[current];
         transform.rotation = rotation[current];
         current++;
     }
}
```

By the way, there are also some more improvements you could do to your Replay class:

1. You don't need to keep a reference to the BallRecorder around when you've already copied its positions.
2. There is no point in initializing `position` and `rotation` to empty List's and then throw those empty lists away and assign an existing list to them. You can declare and assign a variable in one line.
3. According to your comments, you seem to misunderstand what `position = script.position;` *actually* does. It does not copy all the positions. It makes `position` point to the list in `script.position`. In this case this doesn't make that much of a difference, but you should be aware that this means that when the `BallRecorder` changes its list of positions, those changes will immediately be visible in `Replay`. If you want to create a new List which is a copy of everything in an existing List, use [`List<Vector3> copiedList = new List<Vector3>(existingList);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx)

To sumarize, here is how I would write that class (note: Untested!)

```
public class Replay : MonoBehaviour
{

    private List<Vector3> positions;
    private List<Quaternion> rotations;  

    private int current = 0;      

    void Start()
    {
        BallRecorder recorder = GetComponent<BallRecorder>();
        positions = recorder.positions;
        rotations = recorder.rotations;
    }

    void Update() {
         if (current < positions.Count) {
             transform.positions = positions[current];
             transform.rotations = rotations[current];
             current++;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that advancing the `current` counter by 1 every update can cause the replay to play back at a different speed than the recorded action, since Update runs on a variable framerate. You'll also want your test to be `if(current < positions.Count)` since lists don't have a `length` property and the last entry has index `positions.Count - 1`.

Comment: @DMGregory Fixed the `Count` thing. I wrote too much JavaScript recently. Regarding Update and FixedUpdate: The recording used `Update`, so also using `Update` for playback will likely give better results. If the OP should use `FixedUpdate`, they should also do that during the recording.

Comment: Can't transform position and rotation on Update function, as it keeps on replaying.

Comment: @user100020 You might also want to add some methods to the Replay class to start and stop the replay (which can be done by setting a `bool` variable) or reset the replay (simply resetting `current` to 0).

Comment: @Philipp, this time when I'm replaying for the pins, like same done for ball. It says the code is unreachable due to its protection level. I wonder it is because you asked me to individually assign recorder script to each gameObject. How would i access the position of the pins to the replayer script. I tried using with GameObject tag yet no result what so ever.

Comment: @user100020 *What* code is unreachable due to its protection level?

Comment: @Philipp, i forgot to add access modifier to List. Apart from that, do i have to loop around pins position in replay class so as each pin value is transferred to the individual list defined in replay class?